# Should I take (Pen test) approval from AWS for Fuzz testing my Application API's hosted on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, penetration-testing, fuzzing, security-testing

I wanted to Fuzz Tests my APIs on my own stack which are hosted on AWS environment (Have used lambdas and API gateway)

There are mostly GET APIs and only one PUT API.My requirement is to Fuzz Test the API headers and the body. For this I'm planning to use file fuzzing techniques with certain payloads.

Do I need to take a Pen testing approval from AWS for my Fuzz Testing?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you will need an approval as mention below. Please find more details [here](https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/)

> Please complete and submit the AWS Vulnerability / Penetration Testing Request Form to request authorization for penetration testing to or originating from any AWS resources. There are several important things to note about penetration testing requests:

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I had a query like. Im not doing any kind of pen tests here, just that Im passing a simple payload (fuzzing) to my API and check how my API behaves.

Comment: I think just for testing and not pen testing, you can go ahead and check your api via PostMan or something similar tool. That is totally acceptable